# Hive operations from inside script and storing output of it to a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hive, hiveql

I have made a script that is creating hive table and dropping it ,When I execute this script I want to save its output to a text file.
I am executing `sh  myscript.sh > output.txt` but when I do so only text which is in script inside echo get  prints in text file but  when tables creates in hive and its status ok etc does not come into that text file.

Comment: script description : it asks user to provide input like what service operations you want to execute when user prints Hive then certain hive operations are executed and its status like ok or failed displayed at console, i want to take all this status into text file. but after providing input from user nothing goes into text file.

Comment: Just guessing here but maybe you need to redirect stderr as well, i.e. `sh myscript.sh > output.txt 2>&1`. But for you to receive proper help you need to post your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Untested. This works for me for select * .Let me know if any issue comes in.

```
$hive -e "Query" > ~/sample_output.txt
```

You can use this query to load output into HDFS

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/path/to/output/dir' Query;
```